# Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress for a website, but when I run my website, I get the error message specified in the title. It says that the error is in the file functions.php, and in line 32. Below you can find that part of the code:

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Mobile extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

    // don't output children opening tag (`<ul>`)
    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth){}

    // don't output children closing tag    
    public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth){}

    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args){

      // add spacing to the title based on the current depth
      $item->title = str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 4) . $item->title;

      // call the prototype and replace the <li> tag
      // from the generated markup...
      parent::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args); // LINE 32 IS THIS ONE!
      $output = strip_tags($output, '<li><option>');
      $output = str_replace("</option>
</option>","</option>", $output);
      $output = str_replace('<li', '<option value="'.$item->url.'"', $output);
    }
    // replace closing </li> with the closing option tag
    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
      $output .= "</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use reference sign on a function call. Use reference sign only in the function definition ( [Passing by Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) ).

```
// wrong
parent::start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args );

// right
parent::start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args );
```